# how to import multiple layers from tif file with opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision, tiff

I'm using python (cv2) to import a .tif file with three layers, but I only seem to be able to import one layer. How can i separately import all three layers?

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('LanB2_KD1P2_31603_gut_2.tif', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

#extract blue channel
blue_channel = img[:,:,0]

#write blue channel to greyscale image
cv2.imwrite('blue_channel.jpg',blue_channel)
```

this extracts the blue channel from the first layer but idk how to get the other layers

Comment: Try `green_channel = img[:,:,1]`, red is 2.

Comment: Do you want layers/pages or color channels? Your question is about layers, but you are trying to access color channels. If you want multi-pages, see https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga4dd47c9ae3d55cc42286cff005825e31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `cv2.split` for splitting image channels.

```py
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('LanB2_KD1P2_31603_gut_2.tif', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

b,g,r=cv2.split(img)

### saving files
cv2.imwrite('blue_channel.jpg', b)
cv2.imwrite('green_channel.jpg',g)
cv2.imwrite('red_channel.jpg',r)
```

EDIT 1:
If you want to split multiple images in a TIF file and save as them as separate files as suggested by @fmw42 , here is the code for that.

```py
import os
from PIL import Image

def tifToImage(tifPath,imageFormat,folderPath):
    """ Function to convert tif to image

    Args:
        tifPath (str): path of input tif
        imageFormat (str): format to save image
        folderPath (str): Folder to save images
    Returns:
        int: 0 if successful
    """
    print('tiftoimage: {}'.format(tifPath))
    sep='/' if '/' in tifPath else '\\'
    fileName=tifPath.split(sep)[-1][:-4]
    ### Loading tiff image
    tiffstack= Image.open(tifPath)
    tiffstack.load()

    ### Saving each image to output folder
    for i in range(tiffstack.n_frames):
        tiffstack.seek(i)
        pageName= fileName + '_{:05d}.{}'.format(i+1,imageFormat)
        imagePath = os.path.join(folderPath,pageName)
        tiffstack.save(imagePath)
    return 0
```

The function call will be something like

```py
tifToImage('LanB2_KD1P2_31603_gut_2.tif','jpg','out_folder')
```

Comment: He wants layers/pages, not channels.

Comment: @fmw42, I have added the code to save different pages in TIF to jpg .

Comment: @plotka Happy to help. Please upvote the answer too if you found this helpful :D

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler, you can use cv2.imreadmulti:

```
ret, image = cv2.imreadmulti('LanB2_KD1P2_31603_gut_2.tif', [], cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
```

You can then access each layer by their indexes (eg. image[0]).